# remove files that are in find result

Tags: linux, find, rm

I want to remove all files that have ".json" extension. so I run

```
find . -name "*.json"
```

this will result in some files

> x.json
> y.json
> z.json

then I do `rm` for each file, but this is a very tedious task when you have many files.

is there any way to mix `rm` with `find` result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using GNU find, it's dead simple:

```
find directory/ -name "*.json" -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-exec` option with `find`.

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I'd use `-exec rm -f {} +`, which will pass multiple files to `rm` at once, kind of like using `xargs`. More efficient that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` which will give found files to another command.

The advantage on `-exec` is that does not create one new process per file:

```
find . -name "*.json" | xargs rm
```